# Excel Formula which will count all different values and create a ranking scheme out of it

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following data

[image]

I need a formula which counts all different names combined with the team name (just in case that two teams have a player with the same name) and sorts them according to their frequency of occurrence

I edited this as the sample data is maybe more confusing then the real one.

I can't really rearange the data but i can use a new sheet/table to do calculations or whatever

Just to provide some information for example column F is the minute column G the name and Column H the Team (1 for team in column A, 2 for Team in column B)

Comment: There's an answer to this question, but it's long and complicated because your data is stored in an unorganized manner. If you reorganize your data, you can actually get very close to your goal simply using a pivot table. I suggest you group all your days into a single contiguous list, and either use shop names instead of IDs, or use `vlookup` to automatically fetch names.

Comment: Does the shop list and the name list remain static through time? If not seems like a bit of a tall order just using Excel Formulas. Generating a table dynamically is hard to code using this limited tool set. And formulas can't sort a table (though you can AutoFilter manually). Is it possible to broaden the scope of your project to include VBA? Or Pivot Tables as Amit suggests?

Comment: Edited the question to display the real data (which is actually the brasilian football league and statistic of the first battle day) . There is no really good way to rearange the data but i can use vba or whatever necessary but never did in excel as i am only familiar with java

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unfortunate data layout and makes reporting difficult. Having to look up the shop name from the shop code does not make things easier. You'd be much better off with a flat table for data entry that looks like this:

[image]

The ShopName column is using a Vlookup to return the shop name, the NameAndShop column concatenates the Shop name and the person name. In an Excel table, these formulas are automatically carried into new rows.

With such a layout, you can create a pivot table with about 5 clicks, no formulas, to arrive at

[image]

If new data is entered into the source table, all you need to do is refresh the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly i can't really rearange the table besides creating a complete new one which would reduce the clarity. I updated my question with the real data which is maybe less confusing then the i think really bad shop example